# COM Control colour(color) bug/problem when embedded in PowerBuilder

Tags: .net, com, controls, powerbuilder

We have built some .NET controls, and we are using them as COM controls in a [PowerBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBuilder) application.

They (mostly) consist of controls with other controls on them, some other of our custom controls, some from DevExpress. All of ours inherit from a common base - and this has the DevExpress LookAndFeel control on to ensure that we can easily change the look and feel of the whole application in a one-liner, if required (we have had to do this twice already!).

The BackColor on all controls is set to the system colour 'Control', and are correctly rendered in this colour (grey for Windows 2000 default) when the controls are embedded in our .NET test forms.

When the controls are embedded in PowerBuilder they are rendered incorrectly with the back colour coming out as white.

Is this a PowerBuilder bug? If so, what is the solution? If not, what do we need to do to remedy the situation? (whilst maintaining the ability to have all controls match a scheme without individually setting each one's BackColour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we set the BackColor of all the controls to "ButtonFace" - not elegant, but it worked.

Also using the DefaultLookAndFeel control is NOT the way to go in general, as there are various bugs

See:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B132331.aspx
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/K18013.aspx